# How can I determine the angle without painting geometry

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I have a question in calculus in two dimensional integrals, which I can solve quickly after painting. But it gets more complicated when advancing to three dimensional integrals.

How can I find the angle of this without painting the circles on xy plane:

$D = \{(x,y) | x^2 + y^2 -x -y \le 0 , x^2 + y^2 \ge 1 \}$

The angle is 90 degrees.

Comment: What do you mean by "angle" of this 2D region?

Comment: The angle of $r$ isn't scalar. It is from $1$ to $cosa + sina$

Comment: And angle goes just from zero until 90 degree. Because we're taking about just on fourth of the circle. @kennytm

Comment: OK so you mean the range of $\theta$ covered by the figure in polar coordinates.

Comment: Yes exactly. I'm having troubles searching for range of angle every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transform the equation into polar coordinates:

$$ D = \left\{ (r,\theta) \middle| r^2 \ge 1, r^2 - r(\cos\theta+\sin\theta) \le 0 \right\} $$
The two inequalities can be combined as 
$$1\le r\le\cos\theta+\sin\theta=\sqrt2\sin(\theta+45^\circ),$$
which is solvable only when $\sin(\theta+45^\circ)\ge\frac1{\sqrt2}$, which means $45^\circ\le \theta+45^\circ\le 135^\circ$ i.e. $0^\circ\le\theta\le90^\circ$.

Comment: How did you combine the two equalities?

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS 1. $r^2\ge1$ is equivalent to $r\ge1$ (note that $r$ is always nonnegative); 2. $r^2-r(\cos\theta+\sin\theta)\le0 \iff r^2\le r(\cos\theta+\sin\theta) \iff r\le\cos\theta+\sin\theta$.